# ElasticSearch + Tire: OR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I have some trouble defining a query with Tire.

**What I have:**

My documents are events. They have a `starts_at` date, and a `ends_at` date.
The `ends_at` date is not required.

**What I want:**

I want to display upcoming events (for instance). I would define `upcoming` as the following:

- `ends_at` date is present AND after Time.now

OR

- `ends_at` date is not present, AND `starts_at` is after Time.now

Right now I'm just doing

```
query do
    boolean do
        must { range :starts_at, { gte: bod } }
    end
end
```

How can I this OR query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way I can think of right now is to use `_missing_` and `_exists_` in the string query:

```
require 'tire'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'
require 'active_support/duration'

Time::DATE_FORMATS.update :lucene => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

Tire.index('events_stackoverflow_demo').delete

class Event
  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  property :title
  property :starts_at, type: 'date'
  property :ends_at,   type: 'date'

  index_name 'events_stackoverflow_demo'
end

Event.create id: 1, title: 'Test 1', starts_at: 2.days.ago, ends_at: 1.days.ago
Event.create id: 2, title: 'Test 2', starts_at: 1.day.ago,  ends_at: 1.day.since
Event.create id: 3, title: 'Test 3', starts_at: 1.day.since

Event.tire.index.refresh

upcoming = Event.search do
  query do
    boolean minimum_number_should_match: 1 do
      should { string "_exists_:ends_at AND ends_at:[#{Time.now.to_s(:lucene)} TO *]"  }
      should { string "_missing_:ends_at AND starts_at:[#{Time.now.to_s(:lucene)} TO *]"  }
    end
  end

  p to_curl

end.results

puts "---"

p upcoming
```

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to answer :) I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Would there be a nicer way to define `starts_at:[#{Time.now.to_s(:lucene)} TO #{100.days.since.to_s(:lucene)}]`? Is this transformed into a range query? Can I use `FROM`? Because 100.days is arbitrary.

Comment: I realized it's just the lucene syntax, and according to the following link, it does not seem to be possible :(  http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Range Searches

Comment: Shoot a question to the mailing list or IRC how to combine the "exist" query with the "range" query....

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Kimchy told me to use * but I couldnt get it to work. I'll follow the thread there. Thanks for your help. (worst case scenario, I could just index the "ends_at" date as the "starts_at" date when it's missing... This way I could always base the range on "ends_at"!

Comment: His answer was actually right, but I had removed the lucene date format, that's why it wasn't working. So you can edit your answer and replace `#{100.days.since.to_s(:lucene)}` with `*`! Thanks for your help.